# Is there a situation where type casting a pointer automatically dereferences it?

Tags: c, pointers

I do not quite remember where [might be wrong totally as I cannot remember the exact situation] I guess I came across a situation in typecasting of pointers where just simply typecasting the pointer, was dereferencing it. But I cannot recall the exact situation where it took place.

I know the way the things work in the usual manner like:

```c
   int main()
   {
        int x=99;
        void* p=&x;
        int y= *(int*)p; //------------------------(1)
        printf("%d\n",y);
   }
```

My main concern is statements of the form (1). The types might not be specific as mentioned. But is there a situation or case where `*` before the `(int *)` is optional? [I mean that though the `*` before the `(int *)` can be omitted and the variable on the LHS shall store the pointer value. What I want to ask is that, even if I omit the `*` what is the situation, that using only the typecasting of the pointer actually gives the data content of the pointer]

Though I mention the typecasting as `(int *)` it can be assumed a generic typecasting, where I am trying to explain the context.

Is there at all a situation where it happens?

PS: I could not sleep last night, because of this issue was bugging me...

Comment: If this is the sort of stuff that keeps you awake at night then your life must be really quite problem-free!

Comment: @obe not really

Comment: ok, sorry to hear that... anyway, I don't recall ever seeing a "dereference by type-casting" but I haven't worked with C for years so better let someone with more (recent?) experience answer...

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: You cannot derefernce `void*` because `void` is an incomplete type, therefore the compiler does not know how many bytes a `void` is. So before you dereference `void*` you must cast it to a type the compiler knows how big it is. The `(int*)` is the cast to pointer-to `int`, and of course the `'*'` dereferences the result of the cast to `int`. But you must make sure you are not passing though `void*` to avoid the Strict Aliasing Rule. [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the only pointers which are automatically dereferenced are function pointers when used in a function call. So the following does not need a dereference operator:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int greet(const char *whom) { return printf("Hello, %s!", whom); }
int main(void) {
    void* pgreet = (void*)&greet;
    ((int(*)(const char*))(pgreet))("world");
    return 0;
}
```

(Live on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d2b42c72762f6df). As you can see in the output, this is not really portable because converting a function pointer to `void*` may fail on non-Posix platforms.)

So that's exactly the same as

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int greet(const char *whom) { return printf("Hello, %s!", whom); }
int main(void) {
    void* pgreet = (void*)&greet;
    (*(int(*)(const char*))(pgreet))("world");
    return 0;
}
```

But it's not the cast which is dereferencing; it's the function call. (Functions, like arrays, can only be used as values in very specific contexts.)

---

The `*(T*)(&buffer)` hack is intended to prod better code out of a compiler. But with modern compilers, you can get efficient code using `memcpy`, which is portable. It doesn't have to be verbose if you wrap it in a function. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tj7PWTK57:

```c
#include <string.h>
int get_unaligned_int(void* v) {
    int temp;
    memcpy(&temp, v, sizeof temp);
    return temp;
}
```

As can be seen, compiled with optimisation enabled, the result is a simple load operation.

Comment: *The `*(T*)(&buffer)` hack is intended to prod better code out of a compiler.*  I'd say most of the time code like that is authored by those ignorant of the fact that memory is not just memory in C, and that `*(T*)(&buffer)` is usually undefined behavior because it's a strict aliasing violation while also risking another level of undefined behavior because of alignment restrictions.

Comment: @andrew whatever. Although I'm not a mind-reader, I'm still pretty sure my depiction of the coder's *intent* is close to accurate, whatever you or I might think of their abilities. In any case, my point is to show that it's unnecessary, and provide code which can be used instead.